# Is Oracle Database Supported in Joomla?

Tags: oracle, joomla

I would like to use Oracle database instead of MySQL in Joomla. Is this possible with Joomla, is there a workaround or a solution on how to implement Oracle database with Joomla? Any information will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is said that it [can be done](https://www.itoctopus.com/can-joomla-work-on-oracle), but it is not a job for beginners and took those guys 3 working days to do it.

Here's why that combination doesn't work by default:

> - The database and table creation script does not work without modification.
> - The connection and the database class are written to connect to MySQL and not to Oracle (so they all use MySQL functions).
> - Some of the extensions use native MySQL functions directly, instead of connecting using the Joomla Database interface (class).

This is what they did to make it work:

> - We fix the SQL installation script to accommodate the Oracle database in case of a new installation. In case of an existing installation, we export all the database, as well as its data to a SQL file, and then we modify the SQL file (using find and replace) to make it work with an Oracle database.
> - We load the modified installation file or the modified exported SQL file into the Oracle database.
> - We then create a copy of the Joomla database class, and then we modify all the functions to work with Oracle instead of MySQL.
> - We ensure that the Oracle drivers are properly installed and loaded by the php.ini file.
> - We rename the original MySQL database (you will know in the next step why) to something like database_name_old.
> - We switch to the new database class and fully test the website to see if some extensions are not working. If an extension ceases to work then it is a sign that this extensions is calling the original MySQL database (which no longer exists because it was renamed) directly.

Hopefully, you aren't a beginner and those guidelines will help you do it. Otherwise, check how much it might cost by visiting the page.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Do you have a recent one?

Comment: You're welcome. That's all I can say about it, sorry.